# How is my daily rep score so high?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

My daily rep has gone through the 200 points limit: I had one accepted answer and have answered no bounty questions. What is going on?

[Daily rep http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/9800/repk.jpg](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/9800/repk.jpg)

P.S. Please let me keep the rep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the 265 it will show you exactly what you earned reputation for. Also there may still be some reputation from the previous day since which will slowly dissipate. Have a look at your yesterday and whole month screens to track this down.

Also it may still reflect the reputation from questions and answers that may have been deleted. They will not come up in the list but the reputation will still reflect until a rep recalculation occurs.

Also I stand corrected but if I remember correctly accepted answers are immune to the daily limit.

Comment: I'm not sure how I've been onSO for nearly a year without noticing that! Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't realize until I became a mod that you can :( Sadly.

Answer (score 6):

> **Showing 2009-09-07 to 2009-09-08; current time ....**

The recent activity page doesn't just show the current calender day when you open it up, so some of that rep was earned yesterday.

Comment: Yes, you should click on "today" link on top and see today's rep.